# It's a five hit combo!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Placed in front of you with a feast meat for a king,
> Offered by the clown that comes with a new, neat thing.
>
> Tastes from the sea when the red girl comes this way,
> Always good with whatever John catches that day.
>
> To tempt you with what the cows try to murder,
> Or at the place where you won't wait further.

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on Francesco Roggia's observation that

> the initial letters spell **potato**,

you are

> **french fries**.

Placed in front of you with a feast meat for a king,

> Burger King

Offered by the clown that comes with a new, neat thing.

> McDonald's

Tastes from the sea when the red girl comes this way,

> Wendy's

Always good with whatever John catches that day.

> Long John Silver's

To tempt you with what the cows try to murder,

> Chick-fil-A

Or at the place where you won't wait further.

> In-N-Out Burger [last clue added with hint from author]

Comment: Excellent edit, you got all but the last clue right. I'll go ahead and accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Not quite. I'll say this much. They say that they'll be quick, and that you'll go inside and outside faster than possible. But there's always a wait.

Comment: Well, i would've never come out with this answer, i could only guess the first 2 verses, chapeau +1

Comment: Excellent! You've got them all now.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I'm not sure I get the title. Why five?

Comment: It's a play on words. Sevrf typically come in a combo. It's also referring to Svir Thlf at the same time.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, it could also be stretched a little to be [Five Guys](http://www.fiveguys.com/)

Comment: You may want to look at my rot 13 comment above. It is what I had intended.

Answer (score 8):

I'm just guessing here:

> Is it something about a Potato? Just because of the first letter of the rhyme maybe that's a hint to the right answer. I don't really know what is a potato about with each line of the riddle, i let anyone else guess it

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for, but thanks for noticing that! It was intentional, it deals with the answer.